# fIm trying to find a string betwen two match patterns and then add that string before a pattern using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Say I have the below line in file named "logs_test":

Sample input:

```
"at 10947 usecs after Tue Feb 23 18:29:46 2021 [119] init: Event=populatedonRestart"
```

I wanted to find a string between "at" and "usecs" and add the string before "2021" in the above line

sample output:

```
"at 10947 usecs after Tue Feb 23 18:29:46 10947 2021 [119] init: Event=populatedonRestart"
```

sed command to find a string between two matching patterns:

```
sed "s/at//;s/usecs.*//“ <file_name>
```

sed command to add a string before a pattern:

```
sed 's/2021/string &/g' <file_name>
```

How can I accomplish two tasks using one sed command? Is there were to use the sed command inside sed to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it for your example (with GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^\(at \)\(.* \)\(usecs.*\)\(2021.*\)/\1\2\3\2\4/' your_file
```

The ways it's working is as follows:

- I remember the stuff in between `\(` and `\)` (these are called capture groups)
- I break the string into 4 capture groups, the 2nd capture group is the
  number you care about. And I put the groups back together and use the 2nd
  capture group twice: `/\1\2\3\2\4/`

Once you've confirmed it does what you want, you could add the `-i` to do the
replacement in-place:

```
sed -i 's/^\(at \)\(.* \)\(usecs.*\)\(2021.*\)/\1\2\3\2\4/' your_file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly for my use-case.